# Why does my ivar become null when reloading fragment through action bar button

Tags: android, binding, actionbarsherlock, fragment, ivar

I have an app with 3 tabs. The fragments for each tab are created with a SectionsViewPager. I've created a `Reloadable` interface with 1 method `void reload(Context ctx);`. On the actionBar I've added a reload button. When the button is pressed I'm checking if the fragment implements `Reloadable` and if it does, I call `reload(this);`.

So far so good...

In the app I've previously included a pull-to-refresh functionality, but because this does not feel very "Androidy" I want to replace it with the above described functionality (reload button in actionBar, when pressed, refresh fragment). The pull-to-refresh function worked fine  by the way. I've remapped the reload function to the new one from the `Reloadable` interface.

Now I'm testing my reload button and the app crashes.

The app crashes because apparently one of my TextViews isn't bound to my ivar when using the reload button. It is bound when I use pull-to-refresh though. The following is the relevant code:

```
mTextView.setVisibility(isEmpty ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

mTextView is `null` when called through the reload button on actionBar. It's not null when using the pullToRefresh functionality that's part of the fragment. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Is your reload button part of the activity menu or part of the fragment menu? I'd recommend putting it as part of the fragment menu and simply calling your reload function from `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: It's currently part of the activity menu. Gonna try using the fragment menu.